# Combine 2 array elements with a separator

Tags: arrays, scala

When there are 2 arrays as,

```
val array1:Array[String] = Array("a", "b", "c", "d")
val array2:Array[String] = Array("1", "2", "3", "4")
```

Is it possible to merge these 2 arrays as,

```
val newArray:Array[String] = Array("a:1", "b:2", "c:3", "d:4")
```

Comment: What if the two arrays aren't the same length? What result is expected?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, exactly,

```scala
(array1 lazyZip array2) map { case (x,y) => s"$x:$y" }
```

zip produces array:

```scala
Array(("a","1"), ("b","2"), ("c","3"), ("d","4"))
```

and then using map and string interpolation target array is built.
Note that zip will create array with shortest of length of two arrays. I.e.
`Array(1,2) zip Array(1,2,3)` will be `Array((1,1),(2,2))`.

Comment: using `.toList` is unnecessary here.

Also, zipping two `List`s together does not produce an array

Comment: using cats (and lists) you could do `Apply[List].map2(array1, array2)((a, b) => s"$a:$b")`